# Scipy and six downgraded automatically after installing Keras

Tags: numpy, scipy, keras, downgrade, six

After I installed keras, it downgraded my six and scipy. I also found out that many other libraries are downgraded also. Is this normal?

Comment: Installing with conda? Better to use pip with --no-deps, and if any dependence is missing you install it separately....

Comment: how did you install it? Normally there is no mechanism to downgrade. I wish there was.

Comment: Which is the platform? Are you using any distributions like conda or canopy? Adding how you are trying to install will help understand the question better.

Comment: I think conda downgrades if needed, after asking. Keep in mind, that sometimes changing a lot of library-libs is needed to fulfill all their requirements. Sometimes there is even no feasible solution. That's where virtual-environments come into play.

Comment: pip install --upgrade keras <------ this is how I installed. I have anaconda on windows. I installed keras under root, that's the only environment being affected. Tensorflow environment for instance, didn't get affected.